# ESSBASE running long

Tags: cube, peoplesoft, essbase

I am new to ESSBASE so I apologize for the newbie questions I will be asking.

We have an ESSBASE Cube that was running fine last week. Average runtime is around 5-6hrs. However, this week it suddenly soared to 11 hrs. Double the previous average runtime. One of the things that we observed is that the SQLs being fired are in INACTIVE state but progressing. Our database admin team have confirmed that only 6% of the total runtime of the cube is spent in DB and the 94% are somewhere else. We are greatly concerned because the cube data is needed by users at an early time in the morning and since it has been completing late for this week, the data they needed are being delayed.

What are the things that we can check?

Hoping to hear from anyone soon. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your log files for the server/cube. You should be able to see entries that tell you how much time is spent on the data load, the calc(s) and other things. It sounds like the cube is spending a fair bit of time in the calculating state but the logs will confirm this.